# Fuzzy text in NSStatusItem

Tags: cocoa, nsstatusitem

I'm displaying a statusItem at launch like this:

```
theItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];

 NSString *theString = [textField stringValue];
 (textField.stringValue = theString);

    [theItem setTitle:theString];
    [theItem setHighlightMode:YES];
```

The text looks very fuzzy. How can I clean up the look of the text?

Thanks.

Paul

Here's a screenshot with the digital menu bar clock on top, and NSStatusItem title on bottom:

[image: Digital Clock on top, NSStatusItem title on bottom]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks rather fine to me.

[image: test status bar with "testing.…" in text]

Okay, not "perfect" but it's more about uneven scaling than "fuzziness."  Is this what you're seeing too?

Comment: The title of an NSStatusItem uses sub-pixel antialiasing.  Thus edges of the glyphs appear to contain shades of red and blue.  The edges of glyphs in, for example, the digital menu bar clock, only appear to contain shades of gray.  This makes the NSStatusItem title appear "fuzzy" by comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried drawing the text into an image and using that image in the `NSStatusItem`?